# Retrieve value from input object plain js

Tags: javascript

I have the following field,

```
<input id="department" value="finance"/>
```

I'm trying to create an object variable containing the field in plain old javascript like so.

```
var $field = $(document.getElementById("department"));
```

I'm then trying to pull the value from the field variable, however it's failing.

```
$field.value;
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$` is generally the jQuery object, which it looks like you are trying to create.

Comment: You say "plain JS" but are using jQuery or similar.

Comment: Like I said below, it was an oversight while working with a third party library who seems to be using both jQuery and plain js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a jQuery object, which is a collection of DOM elements, and the `value` property is attached to the DOM elements.

You should have:

```
var field = document.getElementById("department");

// now you can access field.value
```

jQuery objects have a `val()` method that gets you the value of that property:

```
var field = $('#department');

// here you can call field.val();
```

Comment: Your absolutely correct, I'm working with third party code and was thrown of by getElementById. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the call to `$()` if you want a DOM element, and not a jQuery object:

```
$field = document.getElementById("department");
```

Comment: @LightStyle, Probably a typo

Comment: Typo, yes.  Thanks for the edit @Starx

Comment: It would be better not to omit `var`

Comment: It wasn't omitted, it wasn't in the OP's question.

Comment: Maybe even the OP doesn't know about it and its usage? - you can specify it, "if it is already declared with `var` keyword then it's okay, otherwise use it!"

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to the question.  Feel free to edit.